# Checking out a Git repository by branch or commit ID using JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am currently cloning repositories with JGit using the following:

```
Git.cloneRepository()
    .setURI(uri)
    .setDirectory(createTempDir())
    .setBranchesToClone(singleton("refs/heads/" + branch))
    .setBranch("refs/heads/" + branch)
    .call();
```

However I would like to allow `branch` to also be a commit ID. How could I implement this?

Comment: Could you please describe your workflow? Maybe there is another approach to your issue.

Comment: Sure. Users can enter a branch or commit ID into the application in order to import the contents. I was wondering if there is an easy way to provide either to JGit without having to check the entire list of references in the repository to identify if it is a branch name or specific commit hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While cloning a Git repository, you can only specify branches (or more generally references) to be cloned. This is not specific to JGit but also applies to CLI Git.

A remote repository can be queried for the available references along with their commit IDs, but an arbitrary commit ID cannot be cloned.

With JGit, the `LsRemoteCommand` can be used to obtain all available references without actually downloading the respective history. Or you can specify a pre-known reference with the `CloneCommand` in order to clone the given reference along with its history.

If performance and bandwidth aren't an issue, you could, of course, clone a repository with all its references (`cloneCommand.setCloneAllBranches( true )`) and once it is available locally, check out the desired commit.